# conditional rendering with useEffect() and setTimeOut()

Tags: reactjs

I've got two components in my react application. one of them is for the initial loading that will show some loading animations, and I want this one to render for about three seconds, and the other component is just a counter that I want to render after the first one. how can I do this with useEffect() and setTimeOut()? (or with any other methods)

```
function App() {
  return(
     <>
       <Loading />
       <Counter />
     </>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's unclear for the `Counter` component. Do you need 3 sec delay for `Counter` as well?

Comment: Loading component's duration will be three seconds, then I want the counter component to render (with no delays).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go :

This is just a code snippet showing `useEffect` and `setTimeout`, in your case you can use real component instead of string in below.

Just run the snippet and hope it will clear your thoughts :

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    },3000);
  },[]);

  return (
    <div>
      { loading ? "Loading Component (will be gone in 3 secs)...." : "Counter Component"}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted, Thanks Vivek.

Comment: @OmidJr, Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), below would be fine

```js
const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">{loading ? <h1>Loading</h1> : <h2>Counter</h2>}</div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a state prop that is a boolean that let's you render conditionally the counter. So for example

```
this.state = {
    isCounterVisible: false
}
```

then you should define a function that starts a timeout with the delay you need, for example

```
makeCounterVisible() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({isCounterVisible: true})
   }, 3000)
}
```

Then, you call this method from the useEffect hook and remember to pass an empty array as second paramether so that it only runs once

```
useEffect(() => {
  this.makeCounterVisible();
}, []);
```

Finally, you add the render condition, like this

```
  return(this.state.isCounterVisible ? <Counter /> : <Loading />)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a component state which will first render the `Loading` component for 3 sec and then `Counter` component. Something like this

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const [showLoader, setLoader] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoader(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  if (showLoader) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return <Counter />;
};
```

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-fo3ju?file=/index.js:179-416